# Why does Gdiplus::Region::IsEmpty() require a Graphics object as an argument?

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I wrote this function to determine whether a `Gdiplus::GraphicsPath` intersects a `Gdiplus::RectF`. It works as expected, but I don't understand why I need to pass a `Graphics` object to the `IsEmpty()` method.

```
bool objects_intersect(Gdiplus::GraphicsPath* path, Gdiplus::Pen* path_pen, Gdiplus::RectF& rectangle) {
    // Get the area covered by the path, including its outline.
    Gdiplus::GraphicsPath* footprint = path->Clone();
    footprint->Widen(path_pen);
    Gdiplus::Region footprint_region(footprint);
    delete footprint;

    // Get the overlap between the path and the rectangle
    footprint_region.Intersect(rectangle);

    // Test if the overlap is nonempty
    Gdiplus::Bitmap blank_image(10, 10);
    Gdiplus::Graphics throwaway_graphics(&blank_image); // Is this necessary?
    return !footprint_region.IsEmpty(&throwaway_graphics);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`Region::IsEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-region-isempty)? "*Pointer to a Graphics object **that contains the world and page transformations required to calculate the device coordinates of this region**.*"

Comment: Also, you are leaking your `GraphicsPath` clone.

Comment: I read that (after seeing this question) but that still doesn't really answer the query. A 2D transformation should not be able to turn a non-empty region into an empty one or vise-versa. Perhaps a region can scale to where it gets treated as empty even if it's not?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I'm pretty sure you can have an affine transformation that maps any given coordinate to a single point, meaning, that a transform can turn a non-empty region into an empty region. If you look at the disassembly of [`GdipIsEmptyRegion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-region-flat) you'll see that it is indeed the transformation matrix that's being pulled from the `Graphics` object. This seems like an odd design as none of the regions are associated with a transformation matrix, and the transform used in the calculation is completely unrelated.

Comment: I fixed the memory leak. The most plausible answer is that `Region::IsEmpty()` always returns true if the `Graphics` object has a degenerate transformation (a transformation that reduces the dimensionality of the space). This strikes me as bad design.

Comment: This API appears to have been driven by client demand rather than design principles. Now, in fairness, GDI+ was introduced in 2001, when C++ was new and hardly anyone knew how to design C++ APIs. It's still odd to subduct general utility by incorporating circumstantial state.

Comment: Also see [Transformations of a Graphics Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-the-state-of-a-graphics-object-use#transformations). It's worth to note that It's meaningless to consider `Gdiplus::Region` without a [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nl-gdiplusgraphics-graphics) object. See the [Hit Testing with a Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-hit-testing-with-a-region-use) sample.